# Selecting from 2 tables using session variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a website where users can create SubAccounts and assign them to different locations.I'm trying to  create a page where users are able to see their SubAccounts and the locations they are tied to.In order to achieve that, i'm trying to select and display data from 2 tables where the condition for the SELECT is a session variable which corresponds to a unique UserId.

My Code:

```
$viewuser="SELECT Username,Password,Name,Info FROM SubUsers,Branch WHERE SubUsers.Userid='$_SESSION[UserId]'";
$runuser=mysqli_query($cxn,$viewuser) or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
$rows=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($runuser))
$rows[]=$row;

echo"<table border='1'>";

foreach($rows as $row)
{
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Username]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Password]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Name]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Info]";
echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
```

While i am able to successfully select and display the query, the results are in the form of a cross join, which is undesired.

The Result:

```
Username    Pass    Branch   BranchInfo
Sub1    pass1   Branch1  1st Branch
Sub2    pass2   Branch1  1st Branch
Sub1    pass1   Branch2  2nd Branch
Sub2    pass2   Branch2  2nd Branch
```

Desired Result:

```
Username    Pass    Branch   BranchInfo
Sub1    pass1   Branch1  1st Branch
Sub2    pass2   Branch2  2nd Branch
```

***Question***
****How do i get my desired result?**** I've tried looking into JOINS, but it seems to me that JOINS are used to join tables where they have a column/filed in common.However in this case, while both my tables do have a column(UserId) in column, the columns in both tables refer to different things.

As such, i am trying to SELECT such that SubUsers.Userid='$_SESSION[UserId]' and **NOT** SubUsers.Userid=Branch.Userid as Branch.Userid refers to the SubUser's id.This thus prevents me from using JOINS to sort/display the data.

PS:I can have multiple branchs per user, and each branch can have a different username.

EDIT: Included Tables

Branch Table

```
----------------------------------------------------
|ID    |BusinessID  |UserId  |Name     |Info       |
----------------------------------------------------
|1     |    1       |   2    |Branch1  | 1st Branch|
---------------------------------------------------|
|2     |    1       |   2    |Branch2  | 2nd Branch|
----------------------------------------------------
```

SubUsers Table

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|ID     |UserId   |BranchId  |Username  |Password     |
-------------------------------------------------------
|1      |2        |1         |Sub1      |pass1        |
-------------------------------------------------------
|2      |2        |2         |Sub2      |pass2        |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: @Prix - that won't work.

Comment: @Prix, Steven is not asking the question, ;)

Comment: @doniyor - I could still post my table structure though! ;)

Comment: @StevenMoseley, yeah, but Prix meant it other way. :D

Comment: assuming both table foreign keys - '$viewuser="SELECT Username,Password,Name,Info FROM SubUsers,Branch WHERE SubUsers.Userid = Branch_code.Userid and SubUsers.Userid='".$_SESSION[UserId]."'";` [prepared statments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it guys,Thanks for your input

The trick was

```
$viewuser="SELECT Username,Password,Name,Info FROM SubUsers,Branch WHERE SubUsers.id=Branch.id AND SubUsers.Userid='$_SESSION[UserId]'";
```

Credits go to amigura!